# Update database based on input value

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, sql-update

I have a dropdown box and three input boxes in my webpage. Whenever I make a selection in my dropdown box, it auto-populates information into the text boxes. I also have a Save button next to each text box. This allows me to update that field if it needs changed once I hit the save button. So for example, it works if the I hardcode the dropdown box value in to my update statement, but I cant get it to work without hardcoding it. So I think that I just need to get the Javascript to read which value is selected in my dropdown box. How can I fix this?

Dropdown box code:

```
<div>
<div id="vendor">
<strong>Vendor:</strong>
</div> 

<div class="align">
<select name="vendor_dropdown" id="ven" onChange="updateinput();">
    <option value="">Choose a Vendor</option>
        <?php foreach($users->fetchAll() as $user): ?>
            <option
                    data-name="<?php echo $user['MR_POC_N'];?>"
                    data-email="<?php echo $user['MR_POC_E'];?>"
                    data-phone="<?php echo $user['MR_POC_P'];?>"
            >
                <?php echo $user['MR_Name'];?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</div>

</div>
```

Contact info code that is auto populated:

```
<div>
<div id="contact_info">
<strong>Contact Information:</strong><br>
</div>

<div class="align1">
<table align="left" id="contact">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="name" class="name" name="name" style="margin-left: 5px"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Email:</td>
        <td><input type="email" id="email" class="email" name="email" style="margin-left: 5px"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Phone Number:</td>
        <td><input type="tel" id="tel" class="tel" name="number" style="margin-left: 5px"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

</div>
```

Javascript for editing the info:

```
// ----- Edit Contact Info -----

$(document).on("click", "#contact .edit", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
  });
  if ($this.val() === 'Edit') {
   /*if($this.id !== '.mr_id') {
        tds.not('.mr_id').not('.mr_name').prop('contenteditable', true);
   }*/
  } else {
    var isValid = true;
    var errors = '';
    $('#myDialogBox').empty();
    var elements = tds;
    if (tds.find('input').length > 0) {
      elements = tds.find('input');
    }
    var dict = {}; 
    elements.each(function (index, element) {
      var type = $(this).attr('class');
      var value = (element.tagName == 'INPUT') ? $(this).val() : $(this).text();
      console.log(type);
      // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
      switch (type) {
        case "ven":
              dict["MR_Name"] = value;
            break;
        case "name":
          if (value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)) {
              dict["MR_POC_N"] = value;
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Name\n";
          }
          break;
        case "email":
          if (value == value.match(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/)) {
              dict["MR_POC_E"] = value;
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Email\n";
          }
          break;
        case "tel":
          if (value == value.match('^[0-9 ()+/-]{10,}$')) {
              dict["MR_POC_P"] = value;
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Phone Number\n";
          }
          break;
      }
    })

    if (isValid) {
        console.log(dict);
      //$this.val('Save');
      //tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
      var request = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "update.php",
          data: dict
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
            console.log("Data saved");
          } else {
            console.log("Data failed to save");
            console.log(response);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
          }
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // Log the error to the console
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {

        });
    } else {
      alert(errors);
    }
  }
});
```

update.php:

```
<?php

  $MR_Name = $_POST['MR_Name'];
  $MR_POC_N = $_POST['MR_POC_N'];
  $MR_POC_E = $_POST['MR_POC_E'];
  $MR_POC_P = $_POST['MR_POC_P'];

  $host="xxxxxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

  $sql = "UPDATE Stage_Rebate_Master SET MR_POC_N = :MR_POC_N, MR_POC_E = :MR_POC_E, MR_POC_P = :MR_POC_P WHERE MR_Name = :MR_Name";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindValue(':MR_Name', $MR_Name);  
  $stmt->bindValue(':MR_POC_N', $MR_POC_N);
  $stmt->bindValue(':MR_POC_E', $MR_POC_E);
  $stmt->bindValue(':MR_POC_P', $MR_POC_P);  
  $result = $stmt->execute();
  echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to do all of these to just make an update form. The best way to handle this is first make a select query from the DB based on the special id to get all data from that id, then fill the form values with that data.

After that you have got a form full of the data from the database. Put a submit button at the end of the page(only one). Edit each field that you prefer and click on update.

Make update query for all the fields in the form of they are changed, they will be updated with the value, if they are not they will be updated but only with their previous value or even with the empty value in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a very similar form. I have one submit button on the top of the page. 
On submit: For each line I check if there are any changes between the database and the input boxes (which are changeable by the user)
Then if (and only if) they are different I use an update table query for that row. It's pretty simple and works very well.

Here is a php example:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) and !empty($_POST['submit'])){
    $column_1 = $_POST['Col1'];
    $column_2 = $_POST['Col2'];
    foreach ($_POST['KeyColumn'] as $key => $variable){
        $select = "SELECT * FROM tblTable WHERE KeyColumn='".$variable."'";
        $result = $conn->query($select);
        if ($result->num_rows>0){
            while ($row=$result->fetchassoc()){
                $same = true;
                if (($row['Col1'] != $Col1[$key]) or ($row['Col2'] != $Col2[$key])){
                    $same = false;
                }
                if (!$same){
                     /* update sql on this line */
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I used many loops because I have spreadsheet not one form. But it works the same without loops, just much simpler